# JodaTime String yyyy-mm-ddThh:mmss.Z to DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

hi i am using Joda time to convert my string dates to DateTime objects.

I currently have the following string:

```
2014-02-16T00:17:20.000Z
```

how do i convert this to a DateTime object?

I have tried:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ");
        DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2014-02-16T00:17:20.000Z");
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2014-02-16T00:17:20.000Z" is malformed at ".000Z"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Your string has some milliseconds; but your format doesn't include milliseconds.

Comment: @DavidWallace I thought it was only used in the pattern. Thanks.

Comment: seems like it should be `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")`

Comment: @Reimeus - that seems to throw away the timezone.  I don't think you want the single quotes around the Z.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ISO8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For future visitors, simpler solution:

```
String date = "2014-02-16T00:17:20.000Z";
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
```

Comment: I don't see how is this helpful. Needed a pattern and the one provided in comments does not work.

Comment: how is this helpful? The question is asking about DateTimeFormat.

Comment: @DezUdezue The question is asking how to convert string in a specific format to DateTime object.

Answer (score 17):

This format happens to be the ISO date time format, that DateTime uses by default. You just need

```
DateTime d = DateTime.parse(s);
```

or

```
DateTime d = DateTime.parse(s, ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser());
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be issue is you guys using Z(zone) in caps

i have tested below code works well

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz", Locale.ENGLISH);  
Date date =formatter.parse("2016-09-06T08:35:02.530GMT"); 
DateTime d = new DateTime(date.getTime());
```